# Store a List of Map Strings using Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to understand how to store a List of Maps in Flutter, display it, and later add and subtract from it by index. I started to use jsonEncode/Decode to save the whole thing as a String but I don't think thats the right way and plus I can't add back to it since its a String and not a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` anymore after Encoding. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class Favs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Favs createState() => _Favs();
  }

  class _Favs extends State<Favs> {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> _favList=[{id: 1, bookTxt: Here is my text., bookAuthor: Isaiah},{id: 2, bookTxt: Here is my text again., bookAuthor: Matt}];

    List<dynamic> _newList = [];

  @override
    void initState(){
        super.initState();

        getSavedInfo();
    }

  getSavedInfo() async {
      sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var myFavList = sharedPreferences.getString('myFavList');
      if (myFavList != null){
        var myFavListCheck = jsonDecode(myFavList);
        _newList = myFavListCheck;
      }
  }

    _saveToList(List<Map<String, dynamic>> _favList) async {
      var s = json.encode(_favList);
      sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      sharedPreferences.setString('myFavList', s);
      print('DONE WITH _saveToList');
     }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('ListView Builder'),),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _newList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 80.0,
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(_newList[index]['bookTxt'])
          )
        ),
            );
          },
      ),
    floatingActionButton: _addMoreButton(),
    );
  }

_addMoreButton(){
      _favList.add({'id': '3','bookTxt': 'Here is 3rd text','bookAuthor': 'Johnny'});
      _saveToList(_favList);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decoding and encoding is the write way. Why dont you try `flutter_secure_storage` as a safer option?

On you pubspec, add: `flutter_secure_storage: ^3.2.1+1` as a dependency.

Then you can use `FlutterSecureStorage().write(key: key, value: value)` which is async.

and to read just use `encodedJson = FlutterSecureStorage().read(key: key)` which is also async.

Also, you would have to use `yourModel.fromJson(json.decode(encodedJson))`, so make sure you also add `import 'dart:convert';`